# pyspark write csv without extra quotes, null character

Tags: pyspark, escaping, export-to-csv, double-quotes

I have a pyspark dataframe that prints out the below output when I use df.show(truncate=False)
(The first row is the header)

```
~id, ~from, ~to, value:String, value1:String, value2:String
E_1, V_1, V_2, “value”, “value0, value1”, null
```

I’d like to write this to a csv file with non-null **as is** (null can be “” or empty space)

I almost always find occurrences of the below words in the csv with the params I try

```
“”value””
“^@“value0, value1^@“”  or “<0x00>”value0, value1<0x00>”"
```

Could someone please let me know the correct parameters to write to csv?
I’d be happy to post the outputs of some param combos if you’d like.

Reference link -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv

Thanks!

Comment: you want quotes also in the final output?

Comment: Yep, quotes on the 2 strings, not on E_1, V_1, V_2